# LilyPond - How do I create a ChordName context that can stack or show multiple ChordNames simultaneously?

Tags: notation, chords, lilypond, lead-sheets

Suppose I have one melody line that is repeated (e.g., singing multiple verses), but the chords should be different the second and third times through. I want these to be defined in their own variables in LilyPond:

```
melody = \relative c' { ... }
chords_a = \chordmode { ... }
chords_b = \chordmode { ... }
chords_c = \chordmode { ... }
```

Now, with multiple `ChordNames` contexts, that can use a lot of vertical space:

```
\score { <<
  \new ChordNames \chords_a
  \new ChordNames \chords_b
  \new ChordNames \chords_c
  \new Staff \melody
>> }
```

[image: ChordNames, stacked on top of each other]

What I'm looking to do instead is something like this:

[image: ChordNames, stacked side-by-side]

I am able to do this part of the way:

```
\score { <<
   \new ChordNames \chords_a
   \new ChordNames \with {
     \override ChordName.font-size
     \override ChordName.X-offset
     \override ChordName.Y-offset
   } \chords_b
   \new ChordNames ...
>> }
```

[image: ChordNames, moved somewhat]

(Modifying the `VerticalAxisGroup`, instead, might be the key here.)

I was able to achieve it more fully, however, by using a `Lyrics` context instead of `ChordNames` and manually entering the chord properties as markup (code simplified here):

```
chord_kludge_a = \lyricmode {
  \markup {
    C
    \column {
      B♭
      D
    }
  }1
}
chord_kludge_b = ...
chord_kludge_c = ...

chord_kludge_collection = {
  \chord_kludge_a 
  \chord_kludge_b
  \chord_kludge_c
}

\score { <<
  \new Lyrics \chord_kludge_collection
  \new Staff \melody
>> }
```

[image: Lyrics and melody]

But in doing so, it (1) is manually laborious, and (2) lacks the flexibility of regular `ChordName` functions, like transpositions and alternative chords (e.g., redefining all augmented chords to read **aug** rather than **+**).

Is there any possible way to keep all the chords in their own variables, yet display them in a single context, where one is normal-sized on the left, and two more are smaller and stacked, one on top of the other, on the right? I believe the closest way to do it is by modifying the `VerticalAxisGroup`, but my knowledge of its [properties and keys](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/flexible-vertical-spacing-paper-variables#structure-of-flexible-vertical-spacing-alists) is limited mostly to guessing and trial-and-error. (Moreover, if Scheme is involved, my knowledge of it, too, is *even more scant*.)

Comment: Oh, so the context you're using them in is not showing the transposing instrument versions of chords?

Comment: @Dekkadeci - Correct. Those were really just dummy chords I used, specifically to include flats, sharps, minor, and slash.

Comment: I think you've just got your X-offset values too  small.